# How to get full referer URL in Chrome when sec-fetch-site is cross-site

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, jsp, referrer-policy, sec-fetch-site

I have a client website that is managed by client team and post clicking on login it comes to the site which is managed by us. Till now, we were extracting the referer URL from the request header and using it to take further actions, but currently due to some changes in the Chrome browser and Edge browser policy we are unable to get the complete referer URL. It works fine in Firefox and Internet Explorer. This is probably because of the browser policy which is restricting the complete referer URL to be send when sec-fetch-site is cross-site. Please help me with some easy code level ways (Java/JSP/Javascript) to extract the complete URL. I tried exploring few links but none helped me resolving this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mozilla Firefox and Internet Explorer use a referrer policy called ‘**no-referrer-when-downgrade**’. Earlier Chrome also used the same policy but it has now shifted to ‘**strict-origin-when-cross-origin**’ which restricts the referrer URL to only include the domain of the URL.
The resolution to make it work it for Chrome browser as well is to set the policy to ‘**no-referrer-when-downgrade**’ in the page where your request begins from i.e. the initial page (which in your case is the client managed one), which will help send the complete details and the browser’s default policy won’t be applied. You may refer to below link for better understanding of these changed policies:

https://www.w3.org/TR/referrer-policy/